# Grouping with restrictions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. One has the parent_Work_orders and the other has the child_work_order. They are linked by the WO#. Both the tables have a status column which has the value '1'(Active) or '0'(not active). Now it is possible that the parent_WO maybe closed(not active) but the child of that WO be active.

I want to group them in such a way that:
1. If the parent is active show all child_WO with the parent_WO being the header of the group.
2. if the parent is not active but one of the child_WO is active then again show every WO attached to that parent (active or not).
3. If the parent is closed and the chid_WOs are also closed then do not show.

PARENT TABLE

```
WO  part  status  duedate
1   abc   0       1/2/2018
2   abc   1       1/2/2018
3   abc   0       1/2/2018
```

Child Table

```
WO  part  status  duedate
1   abc   1       1/2/2018
1   aaa   0       1/2/2018
2   abc   0       1/2/2018
2   abc   0       1/2/2018
3   abc   0       1/2/2018
3   qqq   0       1/2/2018
```

I only want the WOs 1 and 2 to show when i join the tables with restrictions. Is this possible?

OUTOUT

```
    WO  part  status  duedate
1   abc   0       1/2/2018
1   abc   1       1/2/2018
1   aaa   0       1/2/2018
2   abc   1       1/2/2018
2   abc   0       1/2/2018
2   abc   0       1/2/2018
```

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Sorry i have added the output table. Since in WO "1" theres one child active it should show up and in 2 the parent is active, it shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all work orders satisfying your criteria with a `cte` and then use it to get rows from parent and child table.

```
with all_wos as (select wo
                 from child
                 group by wo
                 having max(status)=1
                 union all
                 select wo from parent where status=1
                ) 
select p.*,1 as col
from parent p
where wo in (select wo from all_wos)
union all
select c.*,2 as col
from child
where wo in (select wo from all_wos) 
order by col,status,duedate
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vamsi's solution, you can also solve this with a `SELECT` that has a `WHERE EXISTS(any row with this WO where Status=1 in either table)`

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION` two table and select all WOs that have at least `status = 1`.

> parent_WO being the header of the group

You can use a extra priority column and sort by it.

```
;with temp as
(
    select *, 1 as ObjPriority from @Parent
    UNION ALL 
    select *, 2 as ObjPriority from @Child
)
select * from temp
where WO IN ( select distinct WO from temp where status = 1) -- at least status = 1
order by ObjPriority -- parent is header
```